# Is it possible to use an external library to extend functionality of cloud sql postgres?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, google-cloud-sql

There are external libraries that can be installed used with postgres, I'm wondering if something similar can be done with AWS RDS postgres or Google Cloud SQL postgres.

For example the Bingo library adds cheminformatics functionality to postgres:
http://lifescience.opensource.epam.com/bingo/bingo-postgres.html
Could Bingo be added to a AWS RDS or Cloud SQL postgres instance?

If either of these are possible, could you point me towards documentation or search terms I can use to learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a definitive answer from AWS support that one cannot do this on RDS postgres.  They have a list of libraries they already support here:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.FeatureSupport.Extensions.96x

And an email address you can write to requesting additional ones:  rds-postgres-extensions-request@amazon.com
(I requested they add Bingo).

Here is the equivalent page listing extensions supported by Google Cloud SQL:
https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/extensions

Equivalently, they recommended the GCP issue tracker forum, tagged with Cloud SQL etc. to request support for the extension, which I did here for example:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117212334

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Bingo cannot be installed on AWS RDS nor Google Cloud SQL.

The installation process for Cloud Bingo requires you to install shared objects on the file-system itself (as opposed to an `extension` installed for your particular database). A cloud provider will not grant you administrative permission on the underlying file-system to perform such a task.